# How to continue copying data in different Excel column, when met the condition? Python Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

The file looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkvSD.png)
... (and the same pattern is repeated 120 times, but number of values between two texts, are different)

All data is one column. I want to take all the data between both texts and copy into next column in new workbook (or worksheet nvm). Shortly I start to check all items in this column and if the value is digit, I copying it in new workbook.
I want do this:

A         B
Text     Text
123      434
12343    554
545

```
A         B
Text     Text
123      434
12343    554
545
```

Instead of this with my code I receive this:
A
123
12343
545
434
554

```
A
123
12343
545
434
554
```

```
import openpyxl as xl
work_list = []
filename = "C:\\\Desktop\\all.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

filename1 = "C:\\Desktop\\Empty.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.active
max_row = ws1.max_row
max_col = ws1.max_column

for i in range(1, max_row+1):
    for j in range(1,max_col+1):
        c = ws1.cell(row=i, column=j)
        c.value = str(c.value)
        if c.value.isdigit():
            ws2.cell(row=i, column=j).value = c.value
  
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Can you help me with the use? I start with Python quite recently and I need a little support.
Thank you to all of you in advance.

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text.

Comment: my bad, I saw VBA and didn't finish reading

Comment: Can't you convert it to `csv`?

Comment: @SNR: How does that help modify an Excel file?

Comment: @ScottHunter to work with the `reader` and `writer` from `import csv`.

Comment: Why is your code reading from multiple columns of the source file, if all of the data is in the first column?

Comment: Because, I need to create some graph and extract diffrrent data. In fact my file is combined *.csv files.I have 120 different files,I need information from first column of each of this 120 files. I hope that i explained it well.